# Pagination in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, firebase, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently trying to build a simple CRUD application for beginners of Angularjs.
I am using Angularjs + Firebase + Bootstrap for that.

> Here is the ---***[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TAXmsQlSkYhY2isCKIAw?p=preview)***--- for that.

I just wanna add a new feature is the simple pagination for that.
I think

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

may help but I don't know how.

Can anyone please help me !!!!?

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides filters that are perfect for pagination: startFrom and limitTo. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/) is a great base example of how that works. The key is to have in your scope a page index, and a page size. You can then change what page you are viewing simply by increasing/decreasing your page index.

You can see how it works with this piece of HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
    {{item}}
</li>
```

Comment: @TusharPandya, the result looks great, but the process is a little less Angular, and a little more jQuery. You could definitely go with either one, but I am a fan of keeping it as simple as possible.